# How to append to the name of an argument in C macro

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

I have a weird use case in which I need to modify the name of a variable that was passed in C

```
#define SET_PROTOBUF_REPEATED(msg_ptr, field_name, src_data, src_data_length) 
{     
 /*
 msg_ptr->field_name.len = src_data_length;   
 */     

 // I want to do this
 // msg_ptr->n_field_name = src_data_length 

 /*
 msg_ptr->field_name.data = malloc(src_data_length);    
 memcpy(msg_ptr->field_name.data, src_data, src_data_length);     
 */
 msg_ptr->field_name = malloc(src_data_length);    
 memcpy(msg_ptr->field_name, src_data, src_data_length);  
 }
```

Because I am using repeated type in a protocol buffer message, the variable length is defined as

```
n_variable_name
```

instead of

```
variable_name.len
```

eg.

```
variable_name = frequency

// the length have to be n_frequency
```

The reason I want to have a macro that do this is because I have a lot of protobuf messages repeating the functionality of the function above. For the sake of readability and modularity I think it is a good idea to define a new function that take care of this.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try using `##` Concatenation operator. This way: `msg_ptr->n_##field_name = src_data_length;`

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild: I'm pretty sure the backslash should *not* be followed by a space, or anything other than a newline.

Comment: @jwodder : Yeah!! Thanks!!for reminding me. I got confused, actually I faced this problem once where I placed the space after backslash, and it took some time for me to figure that out. Till before I read your comment, I remembered it the other way round!!. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to write a multi-line macro is to wrap it inside a `do ... while(0)` statement. This ensures that the macro works as a single statement. Eg.:

```
#define macro(a,b,c) \
  do { \
    (a) = (b)*(c); \
  } while (0)  /* No trailing semi-colon */

...

macro (x, y, z);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  macro (x, y, z);  /* This wouldn't work properly without do...while(0) */
```

You should put parenthesis around your macro parameters to avoid surprises when someone passes unexpected arguments, such as `macro (t, 1+2, 3+4);` You also need a helper macro to concatenate the parameters. Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
#define CONCAT(x,y) x ## y

#define SET_PROTOBUF_REPEATED(msg_ptr, field_name, src_data, src_data_length) \
do {                                                      \
  (msg_ptr)->CONCAT(n_,field_name) = (src_data_length);   \
                                                          \
  (msg_ptr)->(field_name) = malloc((src_data_length));            \
  memcpy((msg_ptr)->(field_name), (src_data), (src_data_length)); \
} while (0)
```